# Changing the property value after adding it with map to object array does not work

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array of objects:
[image]

In the array I wanted to add an extra property to the objects.

I did this with the map function:

```
returnArray = returnArray.map((obj) => {
obj.active = "false"; 
return obj;
});
```

[image]

later on I want to change the value of the new property 'active' to a new value ("true") in a seperated function.
But for some reason the value doesn't change.

If I change the value of an property that was in the original array, the value does change.

```
var array = getarrayfunction();
array[index].active = "test";              <-- Does not work
array[index].originalProperty = "test";    <-- Does work
```

[image]

Can anyone explain why and how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain how it doesn't work? Do you get an error or is the old value maintained? How and where do you test the old vs new result? Some context is needed here.

Comment: please Give a example of your returnArray

Comment: I added some pictures for some clarification

Comment: Please add a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Currently we are not seeing enough code for that. Best would be to recreate the issue in a stackblitz for example.

Answer (score 0):

Assign new property to the existing object as follows with quote ( obj['c'] = "false").
http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/488358/

```
  var returnArray = [{'a':1,'b':'xxx'},{'a':1,'b':'true'}];

   $('button').click(function(){
     returnArray = returnArray.map((obj) => {
         obj['c'] = "false"; 
         return obj;
      });
      console.log(returnArray);
   })

  $('p').click(function(){
      returnArray[0]['c'] = 'test';
    console.log(returnArray);
  });
```

Comment: It had something to do with the place my 'var returnArray' was at. That fixed my problem. But thank you for the help !